# Button needs to be clicked twice when page is loaded to start firing button event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm running into an issue when my page gets loaded, for some reason I have to click the button twice before it fires an event.

here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ds = DA.DsQndA(1);//pass quiz id to fill dataset with requested quiz.
    numOfRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;//so we know when to get redirected to results page

    //if we are at over max questions then go right to results page
    if (myNum >= numOfRows)
        Response.Redirect("~/QuizResult.aspx");

    Question.InnerText = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["Question"].ToString();//very first question

    Btn1.Click += BtnClick;
    Btn2.Click += BtnClick;
    Btn3.Click += BtnClick;
    Btn4.Click += BtnClick;

}
```

here is my button click handler code

```
private void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;

    var rnd = new Random();

    var qa = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

    qa.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["CorrectAnswer"].ToString(), 1));
    qa.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer1"].ToString(), 0));
    qa.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer2"].ToString(), 0));
    qa.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer3"].ToString(), 0));



    var myQa = qa.OrderBy(c => rnd.Next()).Select(c => new { c.Key, c.Value }).ToList();

    if (button.ID == "Btn1")
        DA.TrackAnswer(1, 1, Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["QandAID"].ToString()), Btn1.Text, myQa[0].Value);

    if (button.ID == "Btn2")
        DA.TrackAnswer(1, 1, Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["QandAID"].ToString()), Btn2.Text, myQa[1].Value);


    if (button.ID == "Btn3")
        DA.TrackAnswer(1, 1, Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["QandAID"].ToString()), Btn3.Text, myQa[2].Value);


    if (button.ID == "Btn4")
        DA.TrackAnswer(1, 1, Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["QandAID"].ToString()), Btn4.Text, myQa[3].Value);


    Btn1.Text = myQa[0].Key;

    Btn2.Text = myQa[1].Key;

    Btn3.Text = myQa[2].Key;

    Btn4.Text = myQa[3].Key;

    myNum = myNum + 1;

}
```

When the page loads it pulls the first question from my dataset, but when I click on a button to select my answer, the buttons text all changes but the question remains the same, but when I click a button again then the change of the question starts working.

I have tried using if(!postback) in my page load event and added almost everything that was in the buttonclick handler, but the question still wouldn't budge until I clicked another then it went normal.

what I need to happen is load the question and answers and only need to click an answer button once and not twice to start the quiz.

I think I explained it right.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the ASP.NET page life cycle. Your Page_Load method is running first, then your button handler so by the time you update myNum in your button handler to load the next question, the same question has already loaded in Page_Load. For more info see the life cycle overview on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

The easiest way I can think of to work around it is to increment myNum on page load (if it is a postback) like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ds = DA.DsQndA(1);//pass quiz id to fill dataset with requested quiz.
     numOfRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;//so we know when to get redirected to results page

     if (Page.IsPostBack)
     {
          myNum += 1;
     }

     //if we are at over max questions then go right to results page
     if (myNum >= numOfRows)
         Response.Redirect("~/QuizResult.aspx");

     Question.InnerText = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["Question"].ToString();

     Btn1.Click += BtnClick;
     Btn2.Click += BtnClick;
     Btn3.Click += BtnClick;
     Btn4.Click += BtnClick;

}
```

The other option is to try Loading your question in the LoadComplete event which runs after the button handlers like this:

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numOfRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;//so we know when to get redirected to results page

    //if we are at over max questions then go right to results page
    if (myNum >= numOfRows)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/QuizResult.aspx");
    }

    Question.InnerText = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["Question"].ToString();//very first question
}
```

You may need to add some of the changes from your button handler in this method as well so they load correctly for the new question. Otherwise you may load the new question with the wrong answers.

Comment: I'm going to try this out sometime tonight

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your event wiring

```
Btn1.Click += BtnClick;
Btn2.Click += BtnClick;
Btn3.Click += BtnClick;
Btn4.Click += BtnClick;
```

..in Page_Init; Page_Load is too late in the lifecycle

Comment: I tried that and it threw everything off, the values were mixing up

Comment: That's because you're not routing your logic correctly in PageLoad based on whether IsPostback is true or not. The first two statements in PageLoad are executed on every request - I'm not sure you want to do that. Also, how are you persisting 'myNum' between postbacks ? Have you tried setting a breakpoint and inspecting the values of your variables on each request ?

Comment: I seen where I had went wrong with adding the event handlers to the PageInit, when I had added them there I had forgotten to comment them out of the PageLoad. That was why it was throwing me errors. I'm persisting myNum as a protected static int, then I just iterate in the click event and use that to iterate throw my dataset. I've set breakpoints on the event handler and step through everything. The issue is in the pageload, for some reason I need a postback to get the quiz started, so now I have it when the page loads it asks "Ready to Start?!" user clicks button, and causes my postback ...